# How to disable SSL verification for any request?

Tags: node.js, ssl, postman

I have a Node.JS service running, which I am trying to connect from a  different system. Currently using POSTMAN to test the service. Postman gives an error:

> There was an error connecting to https‍://lddbbtx.wdf......./index.xsjs.

Now, I retried the request by disabling 'SSL certification verification' option in Postman and it seems to work. I can receive the response from the service.

But in production, we will be using Recast.AI to connect to this service. In Recast, they provide a means to set Headers for the GET/POST requests. So, I wanted to know, is there a way to disable the SSL verification in the header of the request?

Comment: HTTP headers have nothing to do with SSL verification. SSL resides in the _transmission layer_, but HTTP is in the _application layer_.

Comment: So, do I need to make changes in the server side ?

Comment: Probably, the HTTP client library that you're using, might have a facility to disable the SSL verification (bad practice), or you can manually add the SSL certificate to the list of trusted certificates.

Comment: On the server side, you would mind to use a valid SSL certificate. You can obtain a free one using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org).

Comment: If you don't want it secure why are you using HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

> ... is there a way to disable the SSL verification in the header of the request ?

Validation of the server certificate is done at the client side. It is done during the TLS handshake and thus before any HTTP request is send. Disabling validation cannot be triggered by the server since otherwise a man in the middle attacker could simply instruct the victim to not check the certificate.

In general - disabling validation or even part of the validation (like checking that hostname in URL matches certificate) is a very bad idea. With disabled certificate validation the transport is still encrypted but the client does not check that it actually communicates with the expected server. This way an attacker could do a simple man in the middle attack to impersonate the server and thus sniff and also modify all traffic.

Comment: My server is using HTTPS and sending the require certificates as it should. But on the client side it is not able to identify the server and as a result the connection is not made. Why is this happening ?

Comment: @BoudhayanDev: It is impossible to tell what is exactly the problem in your specific case . But usually: the server configuration is wrong in that the server sends the wrong certificate or fails to send intermediate certificates, the client does not trust the servers root CA (for example with self-signed certificates or private CA), the hostname used by the client to access the server does not match the certificate, the server needs the client to use SNI to tell which certificate should be used but the client does not use SNI.

Comment: Okay, so I guess my problem has nothing to do with SSL. Here, the 2 systems reside in 2 different landscape. The requesting client is on Public server whereas the service is hosted on a private server behind a firewall. That's why it is not able to communicate. The reason POSTMAN works is probably because postman is connected to internal network. I tried connecting POSTMAN to different network and as a result, the service is not reachable now.